# Is it possible to prove a contradiction with natural deduction by negating the formula?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I want to show that a formula is a contradiction. Assume a very simple one like

$$ 1. \exists x Px \land \neg\exists x Px $$

Now negate the formula to

$$ 2. \neg(\exists x Px \land \neg\exists x Px) $$
$$ 3. \neg\exists x Px \lor \exists x Px $$
That is a tautology so one can follow that the negation of 2. is a contradiction so 1. is a contradiction as well. Is that possible for every contradiction?
Or is a semantic proof necessary to show contradictions (as for contingent formular)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is a contradiction because it is of the form $\varphi \land \neg \varphi$
2. is a tautology, because it is of the form $\varphi \lor \neg \varphi$

Therefore, 2. is a tautology as well, since it is equivalent to 3

So all of that makes sense: If 1 is a contradiction, then 2, being the negation of 1, is a tautology.

Now, as far as *formally demonstrating* these things: in many systems pointing out that a statement is of the form $\varphi \land \neg \varphi$ is sufficient to prove that it is a contradiction. And in many systems, showing that a statement is of the form $\varphi \lor \neg \varphi$ is sufficient to show it is a tautology.

Some systems, however, have an explicit contradiction symbol, $\bot$, and so to show that a statement is a contradiction you either show that it is equivalent to $\bot$, or derive $\bot$ from it (any statement from which a contradiciton can be derived is a contradiction itself).

In some systems you can go straight to $\bot$ from $\varphi \land \neg \varphi$ as either a rule of equivalence or rule as inference, but in other systems you derive $\bot$ from a statement $\varphi$ and a second statement $\neg \varphi$

Likewise, some systems have an explicit symbol for the tautology: $\top$, and they will typically have an equivalence rule to go from $\varphi \lor \neg \varphi$ to $\top$. Unlike the $\bot$, though, formal systems typically do *not* have an inference rule to derive $\top$, because a tautology logically follows from *any* statement, and this the fact that a tautology can be inferred from some statement says *nothing* about that statement.

Instead, many systems will demonstrate a statement to be a tautology by demonstrating that its negation is a contradiction. This is the proof by contradiction proof technique of course.

Now, you actually do something very *unusual*: you negate statement 1, and show that the result is equivalent to a tautology. And yes, while that indeed show that the original statement is a contradiction, there would be few systems that would demonstrate statements to be a contradiction in this manner. As explained above, this would only work if you with equivalence rules only, and most such systems have a much more direct way to demonstrate a statement to be a contradiction.

Indeed, if you are talking about natural deduction, then you are probably talking about a system of *inference*, and remember that if you end up *inferring* a tautology from the negation of some statement, then that tells us *nothing* about the nature of that negation, and thus *nothing* about the original statement either.

So no, you typically do *not* demonstrate a statement to be a tautology using natural deduction by negating it and seeing what happens. Or, put differently, while a proof by contradiction demonstrates a statement to be a tautology by showing that the negation of that statement leads to a contradiction, in *natural deduction* there is no parallel proof technique that shows a statement to be a contradiction by showing that its negation leads to a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

*Details may change according to the proof system*...

In [Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) there is (quite often) a specific symbol to denote a generic contradicition : [$\bot$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)) (aka : *falsum*).

In this case, we say that a formula $\varphi$ is a [contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction#In_formal_logic) when we have : $\varphi \vdash \bot$.

In the case of a formula having the "syntactical form" of a contradicition, i.e. $\varphi \land \lnot \varphi$, it is enough to use $(\land \text E)$ rule followed by $(\lnot \text E)$ to derive : $(\varphi \land \lnot \varphi) \vdash \bot$.

---

For a formula $\varphi$ whatever, if we have proved that it is a contradicition, i.e. we have :

> $\varphi \vdash \bot$,

it is enough to use $(\lnot \text I)$ to conclude with :

> > $\vdash \lnot \varphi$.

Deriving $\lnot \varphi$ whitout assumptions, means - by [Soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) - that $\lnot \varphi$ is [logically (or : universally) valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)) (in propositional calculus : a [*tautology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic))).

Conclusion : for every contradictory formula, its negation will be logically valid.